# fread data.table in R doesn't read in column names

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

When reading in a data file into R, I can read it in either as a `data.frame` or a `data.table` using the `data.table` package.  I would prefer to use `data.table` in the future since it deals with large data better.  However, there are issues with both methods (`read.table` for data.frames, `fread` for data.tables) and I'm wondering if there's a simple fix out there.

When I use `read.table` to produce a `data.frame`, if my column names include colons or spaces, they are replaced by periods, which I do not want.  I want the column names to be read in "as is."

Alternatively, when I use `fread` to produce a `data.table`, my column names are not read in at all, which is obviously not desired.

Check out this gist below for a reproducible example:

https://gist.github.com/jeffbruce/b966d41eedc2662bbd4a

Cheers

Comment: Why did you put that in a gist instead of in your question?

Comment: I highly recommend you change the names of your columns. you're creating nightmares for yourself by insisting they remain as is.

Comment: If what you've got in mind is making your data readable when you create output tables, etc. you can store a separate table to convert between concise column names and ones that are useful to work with.

Comment: I don't have a say in what the columns are named.  I need to deal with what's been given to me.

Also, I used a gist for the data because the data wouldn't fit in the question body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R always try to convert column names to ensure that they are valid variable names, hence it adds periods in place of spaces and colons. If you dont want that you can use `check.names=FALSE` while using `read.table`

```
df1<-read.table("data.txt",check.names = FALSE)

sample(colnames(df1),10)
 [1] "simple lobule white matter"                       
 [2] "anterior lobule white matter"                     
 [3] "hippocampus"                                      
 [4] "lateral olfactory tract"                          
 [5] "lobules 1-2: lingula and central lobule (ventral)"
 [6] "Medial parietal association cortex"               
 [7] "Primary somatosensory cortex: trunk region"       
 [8] "midbrain"                                         
 [9] "Secondary auditory cortex: ventral area"          
[10] "Primary somatosensory cortex: forelimb region"
```

you can see that `colnames` are kept as it is.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I've been a fool all this time.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that might work. I'm not sure if it's the shortest solution or you can do it by clever use of `drop` in data table, but the hack below  does work. The "problem" is the row numbers in your file.

Read in the header file first and then add it to the data table after

```
header <- read.table("yourfile.csv", header = TRUE, nrow = 1)
indata <- fread("yourfile.csv", skip=1, header=FALSE)
setnames(indata, colnames(header))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight as to why the headers are not loaded when I use data.table.  Useful answer.