# Remove NA in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, na, missing-data

I'm trying to do in R something apparently very easy (sorry but i'm very newbie with data.tables) but I don't manage to get the right solution. I try to delete the rows with NA values on a specific column("Ground_Tru". This is my attempt so far;

```
all_data <- fread ("all_vbles.txt",header=TRUE, na.strings=c("NA","N/A",""))
na.omit (all_data, cols="Ground_Tru")
```

I get the message

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 75 cols: OID_,IN_FID,Polygon_ID,DIST_highw,DIST_railw,DIST_port...

however the "Ground_Tru" field has many NA values
thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: If you are using `na.omit` if there is any NA in one of the columns, the whole row will be omitted.  Please let us know how you want to proceed

Comment: `all_data[!is.na(Ground_Tru)]` ?

Comment: @simone, it should be `all_data[!is.na(Ground_Tru),]` to keep all non-NA rows.

Comment: @ParthChaudhary  It is a data.table, it should work without `,`

Comment: Thanks Akrun, in fact this could be the case since I have some columns woth all NA values. However from the help I read it is possible to specify  the column where to check for missing values...

Comment: Thanks @simone, in fcat this works, I was just wondering how to do it with na.omit to speed up teh computation...

Comment: Your code should work, as far as I can tell. There are diagnostics we could suggest to figure out why it doesn't for your input data, but really you ought to create a reproducible example before posting, I guess. Some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 2):

Use `complete.cases`:

```
all_data <- all_data[complete.cases(all_data[, 'Ground_Tru'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end I managed to solve the problem. Apparently there are some issues with R reading column names using the data.table library so I followed one of the suggestions provided here:
  [read.table doesn't read in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767351/fread-data-table-in-r-doesnt-read-in-column-names)

so the code became like this:

```
library(data.table)

read.table("all_vbles.txt",header=T,nrow=1,sep=",",dec=".",quote="")
all_data <- fread ("all_vbles.txt",header=FALSE, skip=1, ,sep="auto", na.strings=c("NA","N/A","")) 
setnames (all_data,header)
test_data <- na.omit (all_data, "Ground_Tru")
```

which seemed to work fine.